How can we apply sensitivity analysis in comparing two ARIMA models, both measuring intervention effect?
I have a dataset of reporting rates collected over an 8-month period obtained from the baseline (4 months) and during intervention (4 months). The goal is to determine if the intervention has a significant effect. I used ARIMA model to compare the observed and forecasted values. All differences were found not significant. However, the rate for the third month during the intervention appears to be a serious outlier and there is need to therefore compare a model in which this rate is included and another model in which it is excluded using sensitivity analysis in SPSS ARIMA modeling. I have never experienced this scenario before and need your help. Thank you.
